# Jmeter - Cannot generate token

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

Could you please help me ?

I want to create a token folow algorithm on Jmeter:

hash := sha256.Sum256([]byte(orderKey + apiKey))
    return hex.EncodeToString(hash[:32])

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use [__digest](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__digest) function, first argument `SHA-256` and second argument string to encode

> ```
> ${__digest(SHA-256,Felix qui potuit rerum cognoscere causas,mysalt,,)}
> ```
>
> returns a3bc6900fe2b2fc5fa8a601a4a84e27a079bf2c581d485009bc5c00516729ac7

Comment: Thank you so much! user7294900
Base on your suggestion, I did it and completed my task,